# Python installation on Ubuntu

Tags: python

I am trying to upgrade the python version from 2.7.6 to 3.7.3 but I am getting following error on Ubuntu:

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

The command I am using to update python version is

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

```
sudo apt-get clean all
```

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7.3
```